# Problem using "dataProvider.removeItem" in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to remove an item from my dataprovider where the label in dataprovide is "zee4"

I tried:

```
var removeThis:Object = mylist.dataProvider[selIndex].alias;
mylist.dataProvider.removeItem(removeThis);
```

But this does not work. I cannot use removeItemAt because I don't know the index number. I need to remove as per the alias itself. The alias is a unique field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var removeThis:Object = mylist.dataProvider[selIndex];
mylist.dataProvider.removeItem(removeThis);
```

The reason your method is not working, is because removeThis is not an item in dataProvider.  Its a property in the item that is in dataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

To remove by value, try iterating through the dataProvider and removing the Item when the comparison in true:

```
var removeThis:Object = mylist.dataProvider.getItemAt(selIndex).dataValue;

for (var i:int = 0; mylist.dataProvider.length > 0; i++)
{
    if (mylist.dataProvider.getItemAt(i).dataValue == removeThis)
    {
        mylist.dataProvider.removeItemAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```